# Why is my custom method validating an empty input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a custom method for validating Youtube links, everything works great but it's still firing when the input is left blank.

How can I not have the custom method fire if the input is left blank, but still validate if something is inputted?

Method

```
jQuery(function() {
  var youtubePattern = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;

  jQuery.validator.addMethod("youtubeVideo", function(value) {
      return youtubePattern.test(value);
  }, "Must be a valid Youtube video");
});
```

Validation

```
$( "#addPostsForm" ).validate({
 rules: {
    post_video: {
        youtubeVideo: true
    }
}
```

Comment: [Look at the examples in the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).  All three have one bit of code in common that answers your question.  `return this.optional(element) || youtubePattern.test(value);`

Comment: @Sparky adding that makes all the validation stop working.

Comment: Your problem is that you're not passing the `element` argument into your custom `addMethod` function.  `function(value)`  ~ Otherwise working fine with `function(value, element)`:  https://jsfiddle.net/zp0yg74a/

Comment: @Sparky Yup that was it, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Why not simple add a check for the value length inside the validator function?

```
jQuery(function() {
  var youtubePattern = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;

  jQuery.validator.addMethod("youtubeVideo", function(value) {
      if (value.length == 0){
          return false;
      }
      return youtubePattern.test(value);
  }, "Must be a valid Youtube video");
});
```

Comment: I tried that and it's still validating it.